# Dagger "cannot access SomeComponent" during build

Tags: android, gradle, dagger-2

I started a new project using Dagger 2. The module structure is as following (→ meaning depends on with `implement`):

app → data → network

Each module has it's own Dagger component (e.g. `AppComponent`, `DataComponent` and `NetworkComponent`).

```
@Component(modules=[...])
interface NetworkComponent

@Component(dependencies=[NetworkComponent::class], modules=[...])
interface DataComponent

@Component(dependencies=[DataComponent::class], modules=[...])
interface AppComponent
```

The idea behind this setup is that the `app` module has no access to `network` but only knows `data`. The real structure is more complicated but this is the main principle.

While Android Studio is very happy with this setup, gradle won't compile it.

The error is:

```
> Task :app:kaptReleaseKotlin FAILED
error: cannot access NetworkComponent
  class file for com.somepackage.network.di.NetworkComponent not found

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptReleaseKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

So while compiling the `app` module it fails to resolve the class it has no access to, but this class is nowhere referenced in the source of the `app` module. Dagger seems to internally trying to access it.

If I add a depency app → network the app compiles and runs fine.

Any idea how to solve this WHILE keeping `app` from accessing `network`? This separation is quite important for us.

Comment: [Related issue on GitHub](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/970)